# useContext call preventing subsequent useState update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a provider wrapper around some routes

```
<Provider>
    <Route path={ROUTES.SIGNING}><SignIn /></Route>
    <PrivateRoute path={ROUTES.PRIVATE}><Private /></PrivateRoute>
</Provider>
```

The `Provider` is simply a wrapper for a `userContext`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import UserContext from '../../user.context';

let defaultUser = '';    
try {
    defaultUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
} catch {
    defaultUser = '';
}

function Provider(props) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(defaultUser);

    return <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>{props.children}</UserContext.Provider>

}

export default Provider;
```

My `<SignIn />` Component waits for a response from a data service then 1. attempts to update the setter from userContext and then trys to update it's own useState function. It never seems to execute the internal useState function.

```
function SignIn() {
    const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);
    const [formStatus, setFormStatus] = useState();

async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const result = await signin(credentials);

    setUser({ isInternal: result.isInternal, clientId: result.clientId });
    setFormStatus((curStatus) => ({ ...curStatus, state: FORMSTATUS.COMPLETED }));
}
```

Why would the setStatus never seem to fire? I think it's because setUser updates the Provider which is a higher level component than the child SignIn Page. Any help would be great

Comment: Where is `setStatus` coming from? I only see `setFormStatus` and `setUser `.

Comment: Sorry mistype should only have been `setFormStatus`

Comment: I think it has to do with the `<Provider />` rerendering with the useState update on `setUser`

Comment: Does it work if you reverse the order?

Comment: No either way it seems to not update the user and the form status. User always seems updated. formStatus does not get updated

Comment: I think `useContext` working with `useReducer` would be easier. Also I found this https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14708 it may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race condition. To resolve, you need to specify that your local state update should complete before the context state update.

Solution:

1. Use [React's functional form](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) to set local state.
2. Then call your context state update within the functional set state call.

This way, you know the local state has completed before you update context.